# Protractor find element with multiple div condition in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, testing, selenium, angularjs-ng-repeat, protractor

I am trying to get list of items by checking multiple condition, example want to get file count

Example if I run below code, I get result 6:

```
element.all(by.repeater('releasenotefile in release.releasenotefiles')).count().then(function(count) {
      console.log(count);
});
```

But I want count of Release 1.4 only and I tried the code below, and it returns 0:

```
element.all(by.cssContainingText('.list_subhead',"1.04 Release Title")).all(by.repeater('releasenotefile in release.releasenotefiles')).count().then(function(count) {
                  console.log(count);
});
```

Here is my div structure:

```
------------
Release 1.4 <div class="accordion-section panel clearfix ng-scope" ng-repeat="release in app.releases" ng-class="{active: $first}">

Release note <div class="vz_list_container_01">

    File 1 <li class="bp ng-scope" ng-repeat="releasenotefile in release.releasenotefiles">
    File 2 
--------------

------------
Release 1.3

Release note

    File 3

--------------

------------
Release 1.2

Release note
    File 4 
    File 5
    File 6 
--------------
```

Comment: Your query looks valid, though I'd suggest that you write `element(by.cssContainingText(...)).all(...)` and check that `element(by.cssContainingText(...))` really finds what you need using `protractor --elementExplorer`

Answer (score 1):

I would get everything by repeater and use [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter)+[`evaluate()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate) to filter out results for release 1.4 only:

```
element.all(by.repeater('releasenotefile in release.releasenotefiles')).filter(function (elm) {
    return elm.evaluate("release").then(function (release) {
        return release.number === "1.4";
    });
});
```

Note that, for the sake of an example, I'm assuming `release.number` variable in scope is a release version number - check what variable in the scope is responsible for keeping the release version number.